# Bias corrrection for MLE when dealing with normally distributed small samples

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bias, unbiased-estimator

When estimating the standard-deviation for samples of normally distributed data, it is sometimes necessary to account for bias in whatever estimator one chooses -- which is usually related to the number of observations in the sample.

For example if we take the corrected-sample standard deviation,
$$s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i}^{N} \left(x_{i} - \bar{x} \right)^{2}}$$
we account for sample-size bias with
$$C_{4}(N) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{N-1}}\frac{\Gamma(N/2)}{\Gamma((N-1)/2)}$$
with an unbiased estimator for the standard deviation being
$$\sigma_{\rm{est}} = s / c_{4}(n).$$

For [other estimators](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/astro_refs/BetterThanMAD.pdf) such as $\rm{MAD}$, $S_{n}$, and $Q_{n}$ there are also bias correction factors which also scale with the sample size.

Is there a similar correction factor one can apply when using maximum-likelihood methods? In the plot below I have simulated normally distributed, $ \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, for different sample sizes and estimated the standard deviation with $s$, $s/c_{4}$, and with a maximum-likelihood evaluation. We can see the bias behaviour:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the MLE for the variance and $s^2$ is dividing by $N$ instead of by $N-1$. Therefore, the MLE is $\sqrt{\frac{N-1}{N}}s$.  Hence, $$\sqrt{\frac{N}{N-1}}\times MLE/c_4(N)=s/c_4(N)$$
is unbiased.

Comment: Allow me to play around and I'll accept.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll award the bounty when the timer allows -- can you give me a source or name for this? I haven't been able to find this on Wikipedia.